# Python CSV module, do statement just once in a loop

Tags: python, csv

I want to modify a CSV file with the `csv` module in Python.

In the `for row in csv` loop I have another `while` loop which contains 2 statements that I want to execute just once for every `i`. Here is the code snippet, where `list1` and `list2` are two different lists of strings.

The 2 statements are in the `while` loop. I intended them.

```
f = open('file.csv', 'rb')
csv_in = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

list_length = len(list1)

for row in csv_in:
    i = 0
    while i < list_length:
        if list1[i] == row[0]:

            # Execute the next 2 lines just once for every i
                o = open(list2[i], 'wb')
                csv_out = csv.writer(o, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

            final_list = [row[-2] + ';' + row[-1]]
            csv_out.writerows([final_list])

        i += 1

f.close()
o.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. That code __is__ being executed exactly once for each i. Or are you saying you only want that code to run for the first `row in csv_in`?

Comment: Thanks for responding but Reut solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a set saving which `i`'s were already used.

```
f = open('file.csv', 'rb')
csv_in = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
# use a set saving which i's already used
set_i = set()
for row in csv_in:
    i = 0
    while i < list_length:
        if list1[i] == row[0]:

            # Execute the next 2 lines just once for every i using the set
            if not i in set_i:
                set_i.add(i)
                o = open(list2[i], 'wb')
                csv_out = csv.writer(o, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

            final_list = [row[-2] + ';' + row[-1]]
            csv_out.writerows([final_list])

        i += 1

f.close()
o.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! This works just fine. I don't know what set() does but I will look it up. This is unbelievable. I was stucked with this problem for several hours today and you answered it in a few seconds! Amazing website, amazing community!

Comment: a `set` creates a distinct collection. You could use a `list` but a `set` should be faster because it's hashed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use another `if`, such as `if i == 0:` immediately preceding those two lines.